# Spring Data Redis - Mass Inserts

Tags: java, spring, redis, lettuce

I have the following question:

I have a Java a service reading from a queue and pushing data to Redis (SADD). We originally used Jedis, but I wanted to give it a try to lettuce. 
Right now I am facing some performance issues which I believe that is because of the amount of data we are pushing.

We use spring data redis, and we have a Java POJO we are storing as a JSON. The code we have to do the insertion looks like:

```
public void add(final UUID uuid, final MyPojo... values) {
        final String key = getKey(uuid);
        final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final List<Object> response = redisTemplate.executePipelined(new SessionCallback<List<Object>>() {
            @Override
            public <K, V> List<Object> execute(final RedisOperations<K, V> operations) throws DataAccessException {
                final BoundSetOperations setOperations = operations.boundSetOps((K) key);
                setOperations.add(values);
                setOperations.expire(expiration, expirationUnit);
                return null;
            }
        });
        final Long added = (Long) response.get(0);
        final Boolean expirationSet = (Boolean) response.get(1);
        if (added != values.length || !expirationSet) {
            final String msg = String.format("Error executing commands: Added %d, expected = %d. Expiration set = %b", added, values.length, expirationSet);
            throw new DataIntegrityViolationException(msg);
        }
        if (log.isInfoEnabled()) {
            log.info("add took = {} millis", (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
        }
    }
```

The Connection factory looks like:

```
final ClientResources clientResources = DefaultClientResources.builder()
                .ioThreadPoolSize(4)
                .computationThreadPoolSize(4)
                .build();

final LettuceConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new LettuceConnectionFactory();
connectionFactory.setHostName(getRedis().getHostname());
connectionFactory.setPort(getRedis().getPort());
connectionFactory.setShareNativeConnection(true);
connectionFactory.setTimeout(30000);
connectionFactory.setClientResources(clientResources);
```

Some SADD operations are taking too long (around 10s) ... 
My main question is... is there any improvement that I can apply to improve the performance? 
Maybe partitioning the data, and send a pre-defined number of values at a time? What else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue few weeks ago.

Loss of performance can be caused by variety of reasons.

First of all I would suggest to exclude network issue. [This article](https://redis.io/topics/latency) can be helpful to understand the reasons of latency problem. Also, if you are using remote Redis instance, try to measure time of operations with local instance.

Secondly, you could definitely try [redission](https://github.com/redisson/redisson). That helped me when I had performance issues with Jedis and lettuce, and their API is great. And they have PRO version as well(which is in some cases 44x faster).

Another reason could be serialization/deserialization part.
You can take a look at [codecs](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/4.-Data-serialization) that are being used in Redisson, and use them in your application(FstCodec is, you know, fast).